# When running a GET from an express.js endpoint, how can I sort a specific field (mongoose) that contains an array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have a User schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    subscriptions: [{
        userID: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        subscriptionDate: {
            type: Date,
            required: true,
            default: Date.now
        }
    }]
})
```

and a routes.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const User = require('User')

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {   
        const users = await User.find()
        res.json(users)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({message: err.message})
    }
})
```

My problem is, when I run this GET request, I want the subscriptions to be sorted by 'subscriptionDate' and to only show the 5 most recent subscriptions (and to show all other info like it would for a normal get request).

I'm very new to express, mongoDB, and mongoose, so I hope I explained correctly.

How could I achieve the output I'm looking for?

for the sake of completion, here's my server.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/subscribers');
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', (error) => console.error(error));
db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Database'));

app.use(express.json());

const router = require("./routes");
app.use('/routes', router);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server Started.'))
```

I've tried using `collections.find().sort()`, which ended up sorting ALL users, ordered by subscriptions. I also tried using `aggregate([$unwind])`, which then split users into as many documents as they had subscriptions.

Comment: I guess unwind is a good option here considering you need the top 5 latest subscriptions. After the unwind stage you might consider a limit operation so that the output is limited to only 5 latest subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to retrieve all users, but sorting subscriptions and keeping only five. You could do something as follows if you have mongo 5.2 or above :

```
db.users.aggregate([
{
  $set: {
    subscriptions: {
      $slice: [
        {
          $ifNull: [
            {
              $sortArray: {
                input: "$subscriptions",
                sortBy: {
                  subscriptionDate: -1
                }
              }
            },
            []
          ]
        },
        5
      ]
    }  
  }
}
])
```

You can see my full example on : https://mongoplayground.net/p/4JeDyEYiS4S

I used the $slice operator to keep 5 element in subscription array that i sort with the $sortArray operator (available in 5.2 and above)